# Dynamically defining how an icon is drawn

Tags: java, android

I want to have a "comments" button on my Android e-reader app that displays the number of comments currently posted inside the icon... so basically I want a comment bubble with a number inside it.

I could have multiple drawables, each being the bubble with a different number inside of it, and use a switch statement to choose which one to load each time based on the  `int number_of_comments` field of the element being displayed. This approach seems a little wasteful though, and in any case I have a feeling there's a more elegant way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out this 3rd party created widget

[Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger)

You can use it to create the little number bubbles that you are looking for I think. This gives you the benefit of not having modify your layouts so much to achieve what you are trying to get.

Here is the sample code to apply a "badge"

```
View target = findViewById(R.id.target_view);
BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);
badge.setText("1");
badge.show();
```

Comment: ViewBadger is lovely, but I've ran into some issues with tabs in Android 4+ and the support library. Just a heads up. Icons should be fine!

Answer (score 4):

You can do better. You can have a textview on top of the image view and keep updating its value everytime a new comment is added. You can define the overlap in xml like below and adjust your code logic accordingly to increase the comment count. For now I have just set up a dummy text Hello to show on top of the ImageView. You can add your comment count using the TextView's setText method.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHH as I was walking home just now I had precisely this idea! I was sortof hoping I would be the first to post it here but its nice to see someone else was thinking the same way.

Comment: That was the first thing in my mind after reading your question. However the ViewBadger utility looks promising as well.